# Swift - how to read data from many UITextFields which generate data by UIPickerView

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, realm, uipickerview

I have a problem when I tried to read data from my `UITextFields`.

[image]

I have 3 IBOutlets for textFields (Sex, Goal and number of Meals per day). Data for all of that textFields will be displayed by UIPickerView. I Prepared 3 dataSets, different for all textFields. When I tap on 1st textField (Sex) I have PickerView with Data (Male and Female), after that when I click on 2nd textField (Goal) dataSet on UIPickerView wasn't reloaded but, when I tapped on 3rd TextField (number of meals) pickerView data is reloaded with data for 2nd textField. When I choose something from that pickerView 2nd textFieled are setted (after tapping on 3rd textField!). It always work like the same.
Any idea?

Comment: So you want to replace the UITextFields with the UIPickerViews? Or have one picker somewhere which would reload based on selected text field?

Comment: I want to have one picker view, and when you tap on test field, picker view appear with exclusive data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a `pickerView` as the `textField.inputView`.

The example below is for two text fields sharing a single picker view, but you can extend it easily by checking the identity of the `activeTextField` in the picker view delegate methods.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var myTextFieldOne: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var myTextFieldTwo: UITextField!

    let pickerDataOne = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]
    let pickerDataTwo = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]

    // Holds a reference to current text field
    var activeTextField = UITextField()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let myPicker = UIPickerView()
        myPicker.delegate = self
        myPicker.dataSource = self
        myTextFieldOne.inputView = myPicker
        myTextFieldTwo.inputView = myPicker
    }

    // MARK: UITextField Delegate

    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField!) {
        // Sets tapped textField to active one
        self.activeTextField = textField
        if let picker = self.activeTextField.inputView as? UIPickerView {
            // This is one way to get a reference to the picker view
            picker.reloadAllComponents()
        }
    }

    // MARK: UIPickerView Delegate

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        // You can have a different data source for each text field
        if activeTextField === myTextFieldOne {
            return pickerDataOne.count
        } else if activeTextField === myTextFieldTwo {
            return pickerDataTwo.count
        }
    }

    func pickerView( _ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        // Gets the title for each row in picker
        if activeTextField === myTextFieldOne {
            return pickerDataOne[row]
        } else if activeTextField === myTextFieldTwo {
            return pickerDataTwo[row]
        }
    }

    func pickerView( _ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        // Populates the text field
        if activeTextField === myTextFieldOne {
           myTextFieldOne.text = pickerDataOne[row]
        } else if activeTextField === myTextFieldTwo {
           myTextFieldTwo.text = pickerDataTwo[row]
        }
    }

}
```

You can then access the text in any text field by getting `myTextFieldOne.text` for example.

Comment: It works, Thanks !
One more thing, when I click on first textField and set my data from pickerView, and tap on second textField, I have the same data inside PickerView. I have to close PickerView and reopen it to obtain next set of data

Comment: You can use ```pickerView.reloadAllComponents()``` in ```textfieldDidBeginEditing()``` I have updated my answer with an example. You would need a reference to the pickerView: this could be via the ```textField.inputView``` or it could be declared at the top of the view controller and then just set up in the ```viewDidLoad()``` method.

Comment: It helps but its works randomly. When I tap on first textField, PickerView with dataSet for first textField Appeared. When I tap on second textField, I have the same dataSet. When I tap on third textField, I have dataSet for second textField (and there value are set when I choose something from pickerView), and finally when I back to second textField, I have dataSet for third textField(and there value are set when I choose something from pickerView). Tested on simulator and real device

Comment: I will have to think about what the problem could be. It might need a change of when you reload the picker view data.

Comment: Found issue. I set wrong action for textFiels. Now works perfect. Thanks for help :)

Comment: Great! Glad to have been able to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `UITextView` [delegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfielddelegate). You can use `textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField)` to detect if text field has been selected (became first responder).

Then use the `textField` parameter to detect which text field has been selected and load picker data based on that.